# Detect when Angular component is added to a new ViewContainerRef

Tags: angular

I have a page with a number of simple Angular templates.

```
<ng-template>
   <my-component></my-component>
</ng-template>
```

When the user resizes the page, some of the items are rearranged in a different order (responsive design). Obviously I don't want the content to disappear when this happens, so I detach the views.

1. I initially add my templates to the page with `ViewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView()` (into a custom directive)
2. When the user resizes the page they are detached from the page with `viewContainerRef.detach()`
3. When they should be made visible again they are reattached with `viewContainerRef.insert(viewRef)`

The issue is that I need to tell the component it has been reattached. The specific reason is that they contain videos that needs `play()` to be triggered, but it could be for many other reasons.

The issue is I don't know how to associate a component with a ViewRef/ViewContainer.

1) You can't inject `ViewRef` into a `@Component` so a component doesn't know who owns it
2) The event `ngAfterViewInit` is only triggered when the component is initially created - not when it is 'reattached'.
2) When I initially create the embedded view I *can* get a reference to the Component, but it is contained inside the private field `_view`. I really don't want to access this unless I have to.

[image]

Is there any way to inform a component that it has been 'reattached'? Or some other event equivalent to this (perhaps related to change detector).

Comment: Turns out that _view.component is the parent component, and for the actual component you need _view.nodes, which makes it even clumsier

Comment: Currently my best solution is to pass in a 'key' to the component with an Input parameter. This key is known to the component that calls `createEmbeddedView` so the two can be linked together.